Manipulating the costmap to follow the path between obstacles
I am working on a project where a USV needs to follow the path between buoys. I set up the LiDAR and IMU which I will use to get localization and map data.
The problem is, pathfinding algorithm will most likely stray out of the parkour to find the shortest and safest path between the starting position and goal position. I need to somehow manipulate the costmap so that the plane between the buoys have a lower cost. One solution might be to assign a zero of negative value where the cost radii of buoys overlap though I do not know how I can achieve that.
Any answers about my solution or any other possible solutions is appreciated.
